# Sum of Individual Parameters in an RDL File

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, rdlc, rdl

I am building an rdl report and I want to find the sum of each parameter and the grand total . I have  grouped as per the date and found the grand total,,, Is there anyhow i can find the total of each parameter ,,, like total of a1, a2, M1 here in this scenario,,, what would be the expression for that?

It was possible for me to find the Grand total by grouping on a date,,,  i want to find the total of each parameter now.., like total of a1, a2, M1 here in this scenario,,, what would be the expression for that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQEKO.png)

Comment: asp-net and rdl are microsoft products - is your db really mysql or should the tag be sql-server? Also when you say parameter do you mean column?

Comment: sql-server,,, yes,,, total of each column,,, like total of a1, a2, M1 in the attachment